# Write json object to .json file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

```
var proj = {
    Name : "abc",
    Roll no : 123
};
```

How can I write proj data in JSON format in .json file in javascript?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(proj)` to convert it from Javascript to JSON. It would be worth going through a JSON basics course to teach yourself how to create JSON from scratch though, this is a very basic question.

Comment: You've got 2, identical and working, answers that have solved your problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) (introduced in ES 5.1) will convert the object into a string of JSON.

```
var json = JSON.stringify(proj);
```

JavaScript has no built-in mechanism for writing to a file. You generally need something non-standard provided by the host environment. For example, Node.js has the [`writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) method of the File System module.

Answer (score 17):

You can save the json object in file.json file like this.

```
const FileSystem = require("fs");
 FileSystem.writeFile('file.json', JSON.stringify(proj), (error) => {
    if (error) throw error;
  });
```

Comment: Should be `(err) => {  if (err) throw err; }`

Comment: Works nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same as top answer but slightly simpler version I regularly use to help with debugging (prints out an object at a given point in the code without using a debugger):

```
require('fs').writeFile('file.json', JSON.stringify(proj), (error) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to get a file in a browser with JS is using a dataUri:

```
var dataUri = "data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64," + btoa(JSON.stringify(proj));
```

```
<a download="proj.json" href=dataUri>proj.json</a>
```

cheers,

jD